# Why does Oracle implicitly add SYS_EXTRACT_UTC to index?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle12c, utc

I have a table that contains a TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE column, as well as a INTERVAL DAY(4) TO SECOND(0) column. For the sake of clarity, let's assume the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE
(
 time_col TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE,
 interval_col INTERVAL DAY(4) TO SECOND(0)
);
```

This table contains an index that uses these two columns:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_DELAY ON TEST_TABLE(time_col+interval_col);
```

When running this DDL, Oracle creates the index but implicitly adds the SYS_EXTRACT_UTC function:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_DELAY ON TEST_TABLE(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(time_col+interval_col));
```

The same DDL was run on other databases in the past and the SYS_EXTRACT_UTC function is not present. I don't know if the databases were migrated from older Oracle versions, but currently they all run on 12c (12.1.0.2.0). I've dropped the index on one of them and recreated it, which caused Oracle to add the SYS_EXTRACT_UTC function.

Why does this happen? Was there a change in behavior in previous Oracle DB releases? Also, what could be the impact of having this function in the index (or the lack of it)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure, i.e. do you have the same data types on the old DB? I use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` for long time and the index was always `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC`. Maybe it's just a hidden column, check view `ALL_TAB_COLS` (not `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The columns have exactly the same definitions. I've checked ```ALL_TAB_COLS``` and, in the "old" databases, the ```DATA_TYPE``` of the hidden column in ```TIMESTAMP(9) WITH TIME ZONE``` with a ```DATA_DEFAULT``` value of ```"TIME_COL"+"INTERVAL_COL"```. However, in the "new" databases, the ```DATA_TYPE``` is ```TIMESTAMP(9)``` and the ```DATA_DEFAULT``` is ```SYS_EXTRACT_UTC("TIME_COL"+"INTERVAL_COL")```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way or another, to create an index you have to be able to compare values to each other (decide if they are equal, or decide which is greater and which is lesser). In order to compare timestamps with time zone, you must convert them to a single time zone; UTC seems like a natural choice.

I can't tell if Oracle in older versions actually stored timestamps with time zone in the index, without converting them to a standard time zone first; perhaps it did, and that's why you don't see `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC` in older versions. If so, it's a good thing that someone had the ***good*** idea to use this function, and to store **normalized** timestamps in the index. This makes everything simpler and more efficient.

Of course, it is also possible that Oracle has been doing this all along, and they only decided more recently to ***show us*** exactly what it is doing.

In any case, I don't see any reason you would worry about this. What is the concern?

**EDIT** - a Google search lead me to this article by Jonathan Lewis; he says he started writing about it in 2013, which is when Oracle 12 was released. Perhaps it's a coincidence, or perhaps something did change in that version (either the actual way the index is created/stored, or what Oracle chooses to ***show us***).

https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2019/05/29/timestamp-oddity/

Comment: Hello @mathguy, thanks for the detailed answer. Using the function seems like a good idea, I agree. My concern here is to understand why the structure differs between these databases and if we should rebuild the "old" indexes that do not use ```SYS_EXTRACT_UTC```. My searches also led me to that article and others that mentioned Oracle 12c, but I did not find any actual documentation that could support that theory. Furthermore, Oracle seems to store them differently, as you can see in the comment I made in the original answer, in response to @WernfriedDomscheit.

Comment: I did not fully understand your explanation at first, but I do now. Even though Oracle used to store the timestamps with timezone, it still converted everything to UTC when performing comparisons, such as in ```ORDER BY``` or ```WHERE``` clauses. Most likely, what changed in Oracle 12 is that now everything is converted when the index is created and is already stored as UTC. I performed some quick tests and did not see any problems with the "old" indexes, so I agree that there is no need to worry about it.